# SingleEmailMessage Subject Issue in Sandbox

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage

I am sending an email from Sandbox using apex code but email subject comes with some kind of ID. How to remove this ID and Sandbox . I have work around the email setting also but I could not find it. Please help me out this.

```
List<String> str = new List<String>{'deepak@test.com'};
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setToAddresses(str);
mail.setSubject('Demo');
mail.setHtmlBody('test');
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your apex code.

Comment: Hi @JannisBott , I have edited my post.